# Slow BigQuery response

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got a relatively small dataset where I'm writing IP log analytics then doing queries against it.

I'm updating BigQuery once per hour with updated stats.

I have 110,000 rows with 37MB of data.

The below query takes anywhere from 7 seconds - 50+ seconds to run:

> SELECT SUM(1) as views FROM [statistics.statsLogNSI] WHERE lastedit >
>   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, "DAY")

My more complex query examples are below:

> SELECT SUM(1) as views FROM [statistics.statsLogNSI] WHERE NOT
>   combination contains 'isRobot:True' AND ownerKey = '14013' AND country
>   = 'US' AND lastedit > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, "DAY")

Do you have a recommendation to optimize this result set?  I saw a previous post about 'fragmentation' in BigQuery.  Is updating the table once per hour too frequent?

Comment: That query shouldn't take anywhere near that long to run. Can you give a job id from a query that ran particularly slowly? (if you're using the Web UI you can go to the "query history" pane and find the job ids of past jobs).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Here's a job id.  It's faster today compared to when I posted, but this still took 15s: corporate-videos:job_Pics6cxc_w9_shJKwKxz8WuGfho

Comment: This was just took 160+ seconds: corporate-videos:job_8GR3Pb2ueQUUkjsJn5feFvMmAcA