# Slow BigQuery Response Time

Tags: google-bigquery

I don't really consider this as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400109/google-bigquery-queries-are-slow)
or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130031/slow-bigquery-response). It might be slightly related any way. But, i wrote a simple query on data `SELECT * FROM [opendata.openQueryData] LIMIT 1000` that is not even up to 100,00 rows in total and it is taking forever. meanwhile similar query on sample data `SELECT * FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] LIMIT 1000` just took 1.2s. Is there anything i have to do to achieve this speed on my own data ?

**edit**

And i just noticed the number of rows on my data is not showing unlike the rest of the samples dataset and some i have used before now, Could this be the reason for slow query response ?

Comment: Are you running it from the dahsboard or from code?

Comment: I am running if  the web ui

Comment: what's the average return time?

Comment: Average is over  40secs

Comment: that doesn't look normal for BigQuery, and the engineering team should look at it - can you provide a job id for the query?